# Online poll that lets users add new options?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, survey, hosted

Is there an online poll service that allows users to add their own options? To be clear, this is what it should do:

- I create the poll by choosing a number of preset options
- I send the URL of the poll to potential voters
- The voters can select one, possibly many, options and submit their vote
- If desired, voters can add their own option and vote for that

  - After this, new visitors should be able to see and also vote for this new option
- At some point (not necessarily after voting), anyone can see the results of the poll, as a count or percentage

There are plenty available but none I've seen let users add their own options.

This will be intended for a rather small community so I'm not so concerned about preventing abuse (e.g. vote fraud, adding bogus/offensive options).

If there is a tool that isn't specifically built for polls but do allow this functionality, that would be good too.

Comment: [this]( http://blog.polldaddy.com/2012/02/08/adding-other-options-as-poll-answer-options/) does most of what you want but you (the creator) must manually look at the visitors options,  and click 'add'  (it doesn't add the options to the poll automatically),  as said in the link.

Comment: Why I do not like `polldaddy`'s solution, that if user added an other option, other users are not able to select it, is it right?!

Comment: I have here my own Q: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14613/looking-for-a-voting-system-to-measure-political-opinion-in-certain-topics

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently created a tool that does exactly this. http://www.rkursem.com/poll/

Here, you enter the following:

- Question you want to have a poll on.
- Whether the respondents can select one or multiple answers.
- Whether the respondents can choose from a fixed list or enter additional answers, which future users can then choose among or add another answer.
- A list of initial answers, which can be empty if you want completely open-ended answers.

As creator of the poll, you get an email with link to administration/view of answers and a link to send to your potential respondents. The tool allows the administrator to hide unwanted answers. There is no need for creating an account.

Users can see the distribution as a bar-chart when he/she has responded.

Comment: http://rkursem.com/poll shows 10 words of added answers and there is no way to see omitted words. And for Unicode languages, it even become worse

Comment: I like it. It's really simple, exactly what I needed.
Unfortunately, I can't donate $ to you because the PayPal button doesn't work :(

Comment: Thanks Joe - I have fixed the button - that was an unfortunate bug :-)

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at https://pollunit.com

The poll tool meets all your requirements.
Your participants can also vote without an account. In addition, you have different vote types available such as:

- Yes / no
- Dot voting
- Star rating

Many other optional features are also available:

- Password protection
- Themes
- Own logo
- Own design
- File upload
- Activity Log
- Notifications
- And more...

Here's an example how it can look like:

[image]

**Disclosure:** I am one of the developers.

Comment: anyone, thanks for the answer. Can Pollunit.com display options in a collum, rather than in a line? in this way, participants will go to columns? thanks

Comment: @mike Hi Mike, I'm one of the developers. We decided to present the potentially longer list in rows. We assume that there are more users than options.
In our mobile view, however, the options appear one below the other.
What exactly is your use case? Lots of options? Few or hidden participants?

We are already working on special layouts for special situations, e.g. we will soon release a gallery view for our image votings. Maybe we can also create a layout for your needs.

We also have two different types of PollUnits:
- https://pollunit.com/en/table
- https://pollunit.com/en/voting

Comment: @mike And another idea: There is also a PollUnit Slack App. Here the options are also shown below each other: https://pollunit.com/en/api/slack/welcome

Comment: @mike We recently added a new feature. You can now choose between a table and list view. When choosing the list view you can scroll vertically through your options.

Comment: Wow, a lot of functionality and simple to set up even on a mobile phone. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Trello](https://trello.com/). It satisfies all the requirements that you have specified. Users can add items which may include text, pictures etc. They can comment and vote on the items added to the List.

[image]

In addition to this, you can add a `Due Date`, `Labels`, `Attachments`, `Check list` , etc. to the added list items. Trello is a very useful platform for brain storming and working together as a group.

An example of a Trello Board, with the voting feature can be seen [here](https://trello.com/b/0zgQjktX/blog-post-queue-for-stack-overflow-topics). It is maintained by Nick Craver, Site Reliability Engineer at Stack Exchange.

[image]

Please note that the cards are not ordered by votes. This feature is not supported yet. However if you wish see the cards in the decreasing order of their votes, you may use the [Ultimello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm) chrome extension.

This will let you see the cards that have more number of votes at the top.

[image]

Comment: Can respondents use the poll/survey without an account or logging in?