# Voting system to measure political opinion in certain topics

Tags: web-apps, survey, voting

I am looking for a fair voting system, where more options are available, and user can select more opinion he is agree with. If more opinions are selected than the weigh of a vote should worth less. Solution should be allowed user to add own opinion, but the organiser (me) should be able to specify the most representative opinions, that are easy to select by other users.

Do you know such a solution? I was thinking about Facebook forums and the Like buttons, but it is not representative, one can give more likes for posts in a topic.

Google Forms is also not a good choice, because user can not add his own opinion. (Google Drive is ugly.)

I searched App Store with 'poll' keyword, but from 3 first hit, only one was alive, and it didn't hit my expectation.

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a tool that does something very close to your specification. http://www.rkursem.com/poll/

Here, you enter the following:

- Question you want to have a poll on.
- Whether the respondents can select one or multiple answers.
- Whether the respondents can choose from a fixed list or enter additional answers, which future users can then choose among or add another answer.
- Whether you want to allow the respondents to change their mind (re-vote).
- A list of initial answers, which can be empty if you want completely open-ended answers.

As creator of the poll, you get an email with link to administration/view of answers and a link to send to your potential respondents. The tool allows the administrator to hide unwanted answers. There is no need for creating an account.

Users can see the distribution as a bar-chart when he/she has responded.

Thus, it is very close to what you specify except that you cannot use weights.

Answer (score -1):

I used this http://www.rkursem.com/poll/ poll but after some votes about ~150 it started to mess around. Ones that were first with 30-40 votes suddenly changed to 1 vote.

Comment: So why the recommendation if it does not work properly?