# Online poll for on website that lets users add new options? (without big ads)

Tags: survey

I am looking for a standard poll system which I can use (embedd) on our website. Solutions with subscription model or other fees are ok.

The only additionally requirements are:

- I want to add some initial options
- It should be ad free or have a small branding
- Users can vote on the preset options OR add an option
- Other users should be able to vote on all options, including the ones users added before
- Optionally: It would be great if I can moderate the user options before they appear

Offcourse I did some research.

I found:

- [Online poll that lets users add new options?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/online-poll-that-lets-users-add-new-options)
- [Voting system to measure political opinion in certain topics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14613/looking-for-a-voting-system-to-measure-political-opinion-in-certain-topics)

Both have an aswer pointing to: http://www.rkursem.com/poll/

This is exactly what I need, except for the big ads. I want it ad free or just have a small banner or link.

Comment: [MicroPoll](http://www.rkursem.com/poll/) looks like a personal project rather than a commercial one. Try contacting the site's owner and see if he'll work with you. He may be willing to sell you a license to use his code on your site ad-free, or he might just let you have the source for free.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the developers of https://pollunit.com.

Our tool should meet all your requirements.
You can approve new options in a submission dashboard.

Embedding is possible for (paid) premium users. For premium users it is also ad free.

See also our tutorial for embedding polls: https://pollunit.com/en/tutorials/embed_poll

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.tricider.com/
It's free.

I tested lots of polls but none of them satisfied me for this purpose.
the correct keyword for searching is brainstorming + vote