# Alternatives for Google Moderator / Moderator for Google Apps

Tags: gratis, web-apps, survey

## Overview

As Google Moderator is shutting down on June 30, 2015 ([more Info](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sPmkuVqoHKue7SlL3tSLrDsyufB8owMeR8AHx4LG8FA/pub)) I would like to learn about alternatives, mainly for educators.

## Requirements

1. Web application.
2. Free or Free for schools of any level, from kindergarten (to be used by teachers and staff) to universities.
3. Support / allowed to post in multiple languages.
4. Users should be able to use a Google account to participate. If it allows to use a built-in, Facebook, Twitter or another ID provider it's fine but should include also Google accounts.
5. Should have access/permission/privacy controls, at least include something similar to the following:

   1. Owner: allowed to manage the series settings, create topics, manage permissions. Includes collaborator permissions.
   2. Collaborator: allowed to send submissions and vote.
   3. Viewer: allowed to view submissions.
6. The topic settings should include options to:

   1. a deadline for receiving submissions including date and time.
   2. allow anonymous submissions.
7. Submissions views

   1. All submissions view

      1. Sort submissions to be voted by the user

         1. By submission date-time: newest/oldest
         2. By popularity (total number of votes)
         3. Randomly
      2. Featured submission. Highlight the next submission to be voted. Once the participant vote it, show the next submission to be voted by him.
      3. Submissions made by the participant should be clearly identified
   2. Participant submissions view or filter to display only the submissions made by the current participant.
8. Export/backup for secure archiving and later analysis

## Possible "answer seeds" sources

### Google Web Search

Searching [google moderator alternatives](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20moderator%20alternatives) doesn't offer many options. Should be refined someway or use broader search terms.

### alternativeto.net

It has a [specific page for alternatives to Google Moderator](http://alternativeto.net/software/google-moderator/) but it requires to review one by one.
It has Google Moderator in the Business & Commerce category but should be included in Education & Reference and Social & Communication too, I think.

Looking at the following tags could help to find alternatives that are not documented yet:
feedback-system, customer-feedback, user-feedback, brainstorming, vote, classroom-polls, interactive-classroom, classroom-response-system, audience-response-system,

### Software Insider

http://www.softwareinsider.com/
It doesn't have a specific page for alternatives to Google Moderator. Maybe looking at the [Survey Software topic](http://survey.softwareinsider.com/) could help could help to find alternatives. It has filters that could help too.

### Software Recommendations

AFAIK it doesn't have yet many tags like those that alternative.net alread has but using them as search terms could help. Below there are some findings:

#### Related questions

[Online poll that lets users add new options?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/online-poll-that-lets-users-add-new-options)

## About Google Moderator

---

From

### [How Moderator Works](https://sites.google.com/site/moderatorhelpcenter/getting-started/guide)

> #### What does Google Moderator do?
>
> - Google Moderator allows you to create a **series** about anything that you are interested in discussing and open it up for people to
>     submit questions, ideas, or suggestions. These are called
>     **submissions**.
> - **Anyone** can come to the site and submit a question, idea, or vote, and **anyone** can vote. Google Moderator shows you a question
>     in the box with the blue background. This is called the **Featured
>     Question**.
> - A **topic** is a way to break up your series into smaller, more manageable topics of discussion. You can have one topic, or multiple
>     topics. For example, if you create a series of 'Book clubs' for your
>     organization, topics could be 'Fiction,' 'Non-fiction,' or
>     'Auto-biographies.'

---

From

### [Moderator for Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/114246?hl=en)

> #### Why should I use Google Moderator on my domain?
>
> Google Moderator on your domain allows you to:
>
> - make series and topics entirely internal to your organization
> - invite outside parties to view your series but not participate
> - specify featured series to be displayed on the front page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Kiunei](http://www.kiunei.com)

It was designed to be the replacement of Google Moderator. It has exactly the same features of Google and it's free. You can login with you Google Account, create series, ask submissions, ask anonymously, users with roles and so on.

### **Status: DRAFT**

### **Concept mapping**

Key: Google Moderator > Kiunei

Series > Events
Topics > Questions

### Requirements fulfillment

> 1. Web application

Yes

> 2. Free or Free for schools of any level, from kindergarten (to be used by teachers and staff) to universities.

Yes

> 3. Support / allowed to post in multiple languages.

Yes, you can post in any language

> 4. Users should be able to use a Google account to participate. If it allows to use a built-in, Facebook, Twitter or another ID provider it's fine but should include also Google accounts.

Yes, it has sign in with Google

> 5. Should have access/permission/privacy controls, at least include something similar to the following:
>
>    1. Owner: allowed to manage the series settings, create topics, manage permissions. Includes collaborator permissions.
>    2. Collaborator: allowed to send submissions and vote.
>    3. Viewer: allowed to view submissions.

You have roles but for each Serie. When you create a Serie you define who are admins. The collaborators only are allowed for ask and vote submissions

> 6. The topic settings should include options to:
>
>    1. a deadline for receiving submissions including date and time.
>    2. allow anonymous submissions.

Each Serie has a date and time and the admin could block for avoid submissions. It also allows anonymous submissions

> 7. Submissions views
>
>    1. All submissions view
>
>       1. Sort submissions to be voted by the user
>
>          1. By submission date-time: newest/oldest
>          2. By popularity (total number of votes)
>          3. Randomly
>       2. Featured submission. Highlight the next submission to be voted. Once the participant vote it, show the next submission to be voted by him.
>       3. Submissions made by the participant should be clearly identified
>    2. Participant submissions view or filter to display only the submissions made by the current participant.

1. All submissions are only sorted randomly.
2. The participant can view which submissions are pending to vote by him
3. The participant can view which are your questions

> 8.Export/backup for secure archiving and later analysis

No

Comment: Apparently it's gone :(

Answer (score 1):

## [Tricider](http://www.tricider.com/)

### Status: DRAFT

Just added general answer structure.

### Concept Mapping

### Requirements fulfillment

### References

Answer (score 0):

## [Poll Everywhere](http://www.polleverywhere)

Has built a replacement, with free data migration from Moderator: http://www.polleverywhere.com/google-moderator  Educators get 40 responses per question free, with unlimited upvoting and downvoting. Business plans get 25 responses per question free, unlimited upvoting/downvoting. Responses imported from Moderator are free and don't count against the response limits. No registration is required to participate.

### Status: DRAFT

Just added general answer structure.

### Concept Mapping

### Requirements fulfillment

> 1. Web application.

---

> 2. Free or Free for schools of any level, from kindergarten (to be used by teachers and staff) to universities.

---

> 3. Support / allowed to post in multiple languages.

---

> 4. Users should be able to use a Google account to participate. If it allows to use a built-in, Facebook, Twitter or another ID provider
>      it's fine but should include also Google accounts.

---

> 5. Should have access/permission/privacy controls, at least include something similar to the following:
>
>    1. Owner: allowed to manage the series settings, create topics, manage permissions. Includes collaborator permissions.
>    2. Collaborator: allowed to send submissions and vote.
>    3. Viewer: allowed to view submissions.

---

> 6. The topic settings should include options to:
>
>    1. a deadline for receiving submissions including date and time.
>    2. allow anonymous submissions.

---

> 7. Submissions views
>
>    1. All submissions view
>
>       1. Sort submissions to be voted by the user
>
>          1. By submission date-time: newest/oldest
>          2. By popularity (total number of votes)
>          3. Randomly
>       2. Featured submission. Highlight the next submission to be voted. Once the participant vote it, show the next submission to be
>            voted by him.
>       3. Submissions made by the participant should be clearly identified
>    2. Participant submissions view or filter to display only the submissions made by the current participant.

---

> 8. Export/backup for secure archiving and later analysis

### References

Comment: By _responses_, in the Google Moderator lingo, you mean _submissions_, right?

Comment: I already take a look to Poll Everywhere. It could work for small number of participants because of the 40 responses limit and one "poll" at a time. A workaround implicitly suggested is to use + aliases of Gmail accounts, but I don't think that this will work for some organizations. Instead they could use the domain alias provided by Google.

Answer (score 0):

## [Quora](http://www.quora.com)

### Status: DRAFT

There are several requirement that require research.

### Concept mapping

Key: Google Moderator > Quora

Series > Topics
Topics > Questions
Submissions > Answers
Votes > Votes
Comments > Comments

### Requirements fulfillment

> 1. Web application.

Yes.

---

> 2. Free or Free for schools of any level, from kindergarten (to be used by teachers and staff) to universities.

Yes.

---

> 3. Support / allowed to post in multiple languages.

No. Quora only allows questions and answers in English.

---

> 4. Users should be able to use a Google account to participate. If it allows to use a built-in, Facebook, Twitter or another ID provider
>      it's fine but should include also Google accounts.

Yes. Quora allow users to sign up with Facebook, Google, Twitter accounts or with an email address.

---

> 5. Should have access/permission/privacy controls, at least include something similar to the following:
>
>    1. Owner: allowed to manage the series settings, create topics, manage permissions. Includes collaborator permissions.
>    2. Collaborator: allowed to send submissions and vote.
>    3. Viewer: allowed to view submissions.

Partial answer.

From: [What are the main policies and guidelines for questions on Quora? - Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-policies-and-guidelines-for-questions-on-Quora)

> > **Questions are viewed as community property**
> >     Questions are viewed as community property: anyone can edit a question, but malicious edits
> >     and those that change the substantive meaning of the question are not
> >     allowed.

---

> 6. The topic settings should include options to:
>
>    1. a deadline for receiving submissions including date and time.
>    2. allow anonymous submissions.

To be investigated.

---

> 7. Submissions views
>
>    1. All submissions view
>
>       1. Sort submissions to be voted by the user
>
>          1. By submission date-time: newest/oldest
>          2. By popularity (total number of votes)
>          3. Randomly
>       2. Featured submission. Highlight the next submission to be voted. Once the participant vote it, show the next submission to be
>            voted by him.
>       3. Submissions made by the participant should be clearly identified
>    2. Participant submissions view or filter to display only the submissions made by the current participant.

To be investigated.

---

> 8. Export/backup for secure archiving and later analysis

To be investigated.

---

Answer (score 0):

## [Loomio](http://www.loomio.org)

### Status: DRAFT

Just added general answer structure.

### Concept Mapping

### Requirements fulfillment

> 1. Web application.

---

> 2. Free or Free for schools of any level, from kindergarten (to be used by teachers and staff) to universities.

Maybe. They are open to discuss pricing options for organizations and have a free plan for communities. For futher details see [Pricing - Lommio](https://www.loomio.org/pricing).

---

> 3. Support / allowed to post in multiple languages.

---

> 4. Users should be able to use a Google account to participate. If it allows to use a built-in, Facebook, Twitter or another ID provider
>      it's fine but should include also Google accounts.

---

> 5. Should have access/permission/privacy controls, at least include something similar to the following:
>
>    1. Owner: allowed to manage the series settings, create topics, manage permissions. Includes collaborator permissions.
>    2. Collaborator: allowed to send submissions and vote.
>    3. Viewer: allowed to view submissions.

---

> 6. The topic settings should include options to:
>
>    1. a deadline for receiving submissions including date and time.
>    2. allow anonymous submissions.

---

> 7. Submissions views
>
>    1. All submissions view
>
>       1. Sort submissions to be voted by the user
>
>          1. By submission date-time: newest/oldest
>          2. By popularity (total number of votes)
>          3. Randomly
>       2. Featured submission. Highlight the next submission to be voted. Once the participant vote it, show the next submission to be
>            voted by him.
>       3. Submissions made by the participant should be clearly identified
>    2. Participant submissions view or filter to display only the submissions made by the current participant.

---

> 8. Export/backup for secure archiving and later analysis

### References

http://qr.ae/7OeryY

Answer (score 0):

## [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/)

### Status: DRAFT

Just added general answer structure.

### Concept Mapping

### Requirements fulfillment

### References

Answer (score 0):

## [sli.do](http://sli.do)

### Status: DRAFT

Just added general answer structure.

### Concept Mapping

### Requirements fulfillment

### References