# Private poll webapp where participants can add new items

Tags: web-apps, survey

Soon we will have an integration party in our company. We can choose where we want to go, and I'd like to help us mutually agree on something. Ideally it would be something like a doodle, but instead of people - you can insert items, and vote for them.

The site should allow for inserting items, voting, and some easy selection of most popular option. Comments would be a plus.

Comment: Such a thing is called a *poll*. The only special thing you want is that everybody can add new items. BTW I would also require an 'closing' date.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Trello](https://trello.com/). It satisfies all the requirements that you have specified. Users can add items which may include text, pictures etc. They can comment and vote on the items added to the List.

[image]

In addition to this, you can add a `Due Date`, `Labels`, `Attachments`, `Check list` , etc. to the added list items. Trello is a very useful platform for brain storming and working together as a group.

An example of a Trello Board, with the voting feature can be seen [here](https://trello.com/b/0zgQjktX/blog-post-queue-for-stack-overflow-topics). It is maintained by Nick Craver, Site Reliability Engineer at Stack Exchange.

[image]

Please note that the cards are not ordered by votes. This feature is not supported yet. However if you wish see the cards in the decreasing order of their votes, you may use the [Ultimello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm) chrome extension.

This will let you see the cards that have more number of votes at the top.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of the "poll result" screen? Where the items are ordered by number of votes. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Nice! Could you please copy-paste your answer to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/online-poll-that-lets-users-add-new-options ? Thanks!